# Binary Search Tree add method reference get lost

Tags: java, reference, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a custom Binary Search Tree class, and for some reason the value assigned to the nodes are always lost. here's my method.

```
private void add(TreeNode node, int a) {
    if(node==null) {
        System.out.println("node=null");
        node = new TreeNode(a);

    }else {
        if(a<node.value) {
            System.out.println("root > value "+"root: "+node.value+"value: "+a);

            add(node.left, a);

        }else {

            System.out.println("root < value "+"root: "+node.value+"value: "+a);

            add(node.right, a);

        }
    }
}

//root is class data
public void add(int a) {
    add(root, a);
}
```

When I run this, the console screen always prints out node=null, the first if statement never checks false, which means values are never actually assigned to my node. I think the reference got lost somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: When you pass node.left/right and it is null your code is assigning a new value to the reference NOT actually creating a left/right node. Paste your full class code - that will assist us in telling what you need to do.

Comment: You haven't included the code that declares/initializes `root`. How should we know why it's null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. You aren't initializing the root if necessary in the code you linked. You are creating a new node, but never set the root if you need to. (Hint: The first insert will require setting the root!, might want to check this in your public method)
2. When passing node.left / node.right, you aren't ever checking if you need to  set new left / right children nodes if necessary

e.g.

```
if(a < node.value){
    if(node.left == null){
        //set the new left node
        node.left = new TreeNode(a); //STOP CONDITION!
    }else{
        add(node.left, a);           //Recurse left down the BST!
    }
}
```

You are using recursion, so you need to have a proper stop condition. While your code does stop at a certain point, it isn't actually doing what you wanted. For correctness, you need to make sure you are setting new child node references (hinted above in code). When you are recursing left, you are propagating new values down your BST until you finally need to create a new leaf node. Similar thing is supposed to happen when recursing right down the tree.

In your case, you are only ever passing the left / right node values until a null is reached, and never updating the child node references.